# Power Query merge multiple columns at once

Tags: powerquery

In regular Excel, I can write three index/match formulae to translate three separate columns.  (Sometimes I do the match in its own column to aid readability of each of the index formulae).
I can't see how to replicate that in Power Query except by repeating the same merge and expand steps three times, which doesn't feel very efficient.  Is that the way to do it or am I missing a simpler method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, unpivot the three columns, then merge once, and if needed, pivot it back

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Value"}, Table1, {"Column1"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
 in #"Merged Queries"
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh, that's clever.  Thanks.